# On mouseover display part of background image surrounding my cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add a background image to my webpage, hide it and on mouseover display the part of the image surrounding my cursor. I want to do this in jQuery, JavaScript, CSS3, HTML5. Can anyone help me with it please?

Comment: Did you put any effort in so far? Or are you expecting SO to solve this from scratch for you?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to do it (another demo with a delay below that one):

```js
var circle = document.getElementById('circle');

document.addEventListener('mousemove', positionCircle);

function positionCircle(e){
    circle.style.left = e.clientX + 'px';
    circle.style.top = e.clientY + 'px';
}
```

```css
/* Basic styles for the demo */

html{
    min-height: 100%;
}
body{
    background-image: url(http://www.pageresource.com/wallpapers/wallpaper/cute-cat-kitty-kitten.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    min-height: 100%;
}

/* Your circle */

#circle{
    padding: 2em;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: -502em;
    margin-left: -502em;
    background: transparent;  /* Show through the circle */
    -moz-border-radius: 504em;
    border-radius: 504em;
    border: 500em solid rgba(0,0,0,.6); /* Make a huge border to hide the rest */
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease;
    transition: opacity .5s ease;
}

#circle:hover{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle"></div>
```

You can also do it with a delay, to add a visual effect:

```js
var circle = document.getElementById('circle');

document.addEventListener('mousemove', positionCircle);

function positionCircle(e){
    var event = e;
    setTimeout(function(){
        circle.style.left = event.clientX + 'px';
        circle.style.top = event.clientY + 'px';
    },70);
}
```

```css
/* Basic styles for the demo */

html{
    min-height: 100%;
}
body{
    background-image: url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/prod_sussleimg/cbb1ee8720943f710058cd92ce376958.jpg);
    background-position: 0 -5em;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    min-height: 100%;
}

/* Your circle */

#circle{
    padding: 2em;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: -502em;
    margin-left: -502em;
    background: transparent;  /* Show through the circle */
    -moz-border-radius: 504em;
    border-radius: 504em;
    border: 500em solid rgba(0,0,0,.6); /* Make a huge border to hide the rest */
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease;
    transition: opacity .5s ease;
}

#circle:hover{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle"></div>
```